# How do i make Zsh cd completion list all files?

Tags: zsh

I want Zsh to display all files when using tab completion after cd.

Right now tab completion after cd only display directories. I want to see all the files.

Basically i want it to work the exact same way as if i would use tab completion after a command like vim.

Comment: why do you want to list 'files' when `cd` works only on `directories`?

Comment: I want to always be aware about what files i have and where they are. Just because i'm going to use cd doesn't mean i know exactly where i'm going or what i'm looking for.

Comment: but if you start with `cd` a filename is the wrong endpoint, imho.

Comment: I don't care. It would however be pretty awesome if Zsh only displayed the files and ignored them when completing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** got the answer from ft on #zsh @ FreeNode.

```
compdef _path_files cd
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the solution. Does not work for me.